# How to match specific pattern from a string

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I had return a program it will check  which file is present or not and it will check no of column

```
create or replace procedure chkcsvfile
(P_UTLDIR VARCHAR2,
P_FILENAME  VARCHAR2,
P_tabnam   VARCHAR2
)
is
  P_fieldel varchar2(2):= ',';
    V1 VARCHAR2(32767) ;
   P_errlen number :=0;
   lv_a number;
   lv_b number;
   lv_c number;
   lv_d number;
   lv_check_file_exist boolean; 
   v_file utl_file.file_type;  

 cursor c1  is
  select count(*) from user_tables where TABLE_NAME =P_tabnam;

  cursor c2  is
  select count(*) from user_tab_columns where TABLE_NAME =P_tabnam;

begin

open c1;
fetch c1 into lv_c;
if lv_c = 0 then
dbms_output.put_line('table name is invalid : ' || P_tabnam);
end if;

--'test wheather file is  available or not'
dbms_output.put_line ('test wheather file is  available or not');
utl_file.fgetattr (P_UTLDIR,P_FILENAME, lv_check_file_exist, lv_a, lv_b );
if lv_check_file_exist then

dbms_output.put_line('file  ' ||P_FILENAME  ||'  exists');

v_file := utl_file.fopen(P_UTLDIR,P_FILENAME, 'R');

UTL_FILE.get_line (v_file ,V1,32767);

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('V1 :' || V1);

if (REGEXP_like (V1, ',',1))
then
P_errlen  := P_errlen +1 ;
dbms_output.put_line ('errrooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooorr'); 
dbms_output.put_line (P_errlen );

end if;

end if;
if not lv_check_file_exist then
dbms_output.put_line('file ' ||  P_FILENAME  ||'  does not exist');
end if;
if lv_check_file_exist is null then
dbms_output.put_line('file check null');
end if;
if lv_check_file_exist is not null then
dbms_output.put_line('file check not null');
end if;
dbms_output.put_line('lv_a-->'||lv_a);
dbms_output.put_line('lv_b-->'||lv_b);

open c2;
fetch c2 into lv_d;
dbms_output.put_line ('No of columns in a table : ' || lv_d );

end;
/
```

NOW my problem is i have to match " , " in a string and i want the count of it . i had written the program but it not give me specific count .

data in string is given in below format

```
7839,KING      ,PRESIDENT,0000,17-nov-1981, 005000.00 ,000000.00,10,
```

please help me 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using 11g, you can use the [regexp_count](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm) function.

```
select regexp_count('7839,KING      ,PRESIDENT,0000,17-nov-1981, 005000.00 ,000000.00,10,',',')
from dual
```